# Trying To Get User Data From GitHub API Not Sure What's Wrong

Tags: reactjs

I Wrote A Peace Of Code Which If Works Expected To Get Profile Pic And User Name From GitHub API According To User Input. Console Also Not Showing Any Error.Can Any One Help Me Correct This Thanks In Advance .

This I What I Tried So Far

```js
var Main = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return({
            user:[]
        });
    },
    addUser: function(loginToAdd) {
        this.setState({user: this.state.logins.concat(loginToAdd)});
    },
    render: function() {
        var abc = this.state.user.map(function(user){
            return(
                <Display user={user} key={user}/>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <Form addUser={this.addUser}/>
                {abc}
                <hr />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
var Form = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var loginInput = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.login);
        this.props.addUser(loginInput.value);
        loginInput.value = '';
    },
    render:function(){
        return (
            <div onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="github login" ref="login"/>
                <button>Add</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
var Display = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return{};
    },
    componentDidMount:function(){
        var component = this;
        $.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+this.props.user,function(data){
            component.setState(data);
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={this.state.avatar_url} width="80"/>
                <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React JS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="app"></div>
</div>
<script src="demo.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSBin Link](https://jsbin.com/xecuqi/3/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` do not have an `onSubmit` event `form` do however, fix that and you should be ok